# Why isn't this sorting correctly?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

So I'm attempt to take an array like

```
 ["2015/10","2015/1","2015/6","2015/12","2015/3","2015/7","2015/2","2016/1","2015/8","2015/5","2015/11","2015/9","2015/4"]
```

, where the `XXXX/YY` is year/month format, and sort it from least to greatest.

Attempt, using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort as a reference:

```
month_keys.sort(function(x,y){
    var partsX = x.split('/'), partsY = y.split('/');
    return partsX[0] < partsY[0] ? -1 : ( partsX[1] < partsY[1] ? -1 : 1 );
})...
```

and that gives me

```
 ["2015/1","2015/11","2016/1","2015/10","2015/12","2015/2","2015/3","2015/5","2015/5","2015/6","2015/7","2015/8","2015/9"]
```

in the example array I gave at the beginning. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are comparing strings, not numbers. When comparing strings, they are compared char by char so anything starting with an 1 comes before something starting e.g. with a 2. Even if it's 10 vs 2.

Convert them to numbers and you should get the order you want:

```
var partsX = +x.split('/'),
    partsY = +y.split('/');
```

You also need to fix the actual comparison:

```
if (partsX[0] < partsY[0]) return -1;
else if (partsX[0] > partsY[0]) return 1;
else if (partsX[1] < partsY[1]) return -1;
else if (partsX[1] > partsY[1]) return 1;
else return 0;
```

Comment: Are you sure? `'1000' < '2'` is true.

Answer (score -1):

You have strings representing numbers. Just put a '+' before the variable to convert it to number:

```
return +partsX[0] < +partsY[0] ? -1 : ( +partsX[1] < +partsY[1] ? -1 : 1 );
```

I works...

Comment: Is there any difference between using `+` and using `parseInt`?

Comment: the + is one of those neat js shortcuts to convert strings containing numbers. parseInt gives you more power, allowing you to convert binary, hex or oct, not just decimals.